# WPF AutomationElement NativeWindowHandle

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this:

```
this.DialogCDKey = this.ApplicationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, this.ConditionDialogTitleCDKey);
```

When I run and break after this line, I see `DialogCDKey` Info which is an `AutomationElement`.
Scrolling through the info I see the `NativeWindowHandle`.
I want to assign this to an `IntPtr` like this:

```
IntPtr WindowHandle = this.DialogCDKey.Current.NativeWindowHandle();
```

But MSVS does not buy this, where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, did you give it a try?

```
IntPtr WindowHandle = new IntPtr(this.DialogCDKey.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`NativeWindowHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.nativewindowhandle?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Automation_AutomationElement_AutomationElementInformation_NativeWindowHandle) property is of type `int`. An integer can be [casted to an `IntPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.op_explicit?view=net-5.0#System_IntPtr_op_Explicit_System_Int32__System_IntPtr) **explicitly**:

```
var WindowHandle = (IntPtr) (this.DialogCDKey.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
```

Internally, casting an `int` to an `IntPtr` is the same as creating a new `IntPtr` instance, so you can do what you prefer. This is the implementation of the cast above in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,164):

```
public static explicit operator IntPtr (int value) 
{
   return new IntPtr(value);
}
```

Comment: @TBBW Updated with the difference between a cast and creating a new instance of `IntPtr`.